# Exchange 2010 - Getting NDR's with Relaying Denied or Firewall Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

I have setup an Exchange 2010 Server a couple months ago and it has been working great.  Recently (last 2 weeks) we started getting NDR's on some of the email.

> ... Relaying denied. Please check your mail first or restart your mail session.
>
> Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

and

> Firewall Error
>
> A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

I have not made any changes to the server besides Antispam updates and tweaking the Antispam settings (content filtering actions).

Anyone have any tips of where I could start looking?
I was finding information about Receive Connectors possibly being the culprit. I just have the 2 default connectors going.  Should I create new ones?
If so, how would I create connectors that would suffice for us. (Exchange users and also OWA users.)

I can provide any other details anyone needs in order to help me out.

~Aeotrin

**Update**: 
The error I am getting back also looks something like this:

Mail.server.ofRecipient rejected your message to the following e-mail addresses:

Recipient Name (recipientEmail@company.com) (recipientEmail@company.com)

Mail.server.ofRecipient gave this error:
... Relaying denied. Please check your mail first or restart your mail session.

Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

Comment: Are the NDRs received when you send messages out or are they received by people trying to send to you?

Comment: I receive them anywhere from 1-5 minutes after I send an email.  The NDR does not happen everytime I email the contact though, which makes it even harder of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you server isn't on blacklist http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Also try https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ some options to see if you can find any anomalies in your Exchange setup.

Comment: Tried the mxtoolbox blacklist check, and its clear. 2 of them timeout but the rest are ok.

Comment: The Exchange Test for Outbound SMTP Test succeeded with warnings.  Attempting to find the SPF record using a DNS TEXT record query.
  ExRCA wasn't able to find the SPF record.

Comment: Are NDR's for every single email you send or just a few? Can you try to telnet <some_mail_server> 25 port (of course related to the email you're sending to? You can use mxtooblbox.com to find out proper mail server to test.

Comment: I had an email go through this morning, and 1 fail.  I used telnet <> 25 to the mail server and tried this: ehlo    rset    mail from:myemailaddress@mail.com     rcpt to:emailCausingNDR@mail.com and got this response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Comment: Depending on the Spam scoring for other companies, it could be blocking based on no SPF record. I've never set one of those up my self, but it looks like Microsoft has a walk through. Let me know if that works out for you.  http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Comment: Sounds good, I am on the phone with my ISP (They control our external DNS Entries.)  I will let you know if it helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Well if it's a random fail then I would try it on larger scale. Set up an account on google, hotmail and couple of others and see what responses you have. Some companies deny non-SPF based servers but it's not very common practice since a lot of servers around the world don't use it yet. SPF is simple and effective but it's not yet mandatory. Unable to relay often means some misconfiguration. Is it possible that the adress you try to send email to was hosting your email domain earlier? They tend to forget to switch off that properly.

Comment: What I dont understand is why it would only start happening a couple of weeks ago.  It worked fine, with no NDR's for the first month and a half.  I will have to look into whether they had hosted our email in the past.  I dont think so as that company is smaller non-local and we probably would not have looked that far away.

Comment: Also check if the emails you are sending in outlook (in sent folder) when you double click on receiver if it says SMTP <someonone>. I had this case few days ago when mails would be bounced because user had MAILTO instead of SMTP in properties of such contact.

Comment: Checked the SMTP problem and that is fine. We were never under that companies email hosting either.

Comment: Ok, well verify if it's only one email provider or many? Test it out with 5-10 recipients .. maybe check what other users are sending in console and if they receive any NDR. It's possible that the other company has problem and not you..

Comment: I have had mail NDR'd from another business, accountant, microsoft business contact. So I know it is from multiple providers.  These have all been a case of some go through and some get return with the relay denied error.

Comment: MXToolbox that's linked here does a relay check as well. Does that come back green? You could also try to telnet into their server. Check for their MX record and telnet into that on port 25. That might give you some more insite into the issue.

Comment: It does come back as green "Not an open relay."  I have altered my receive connectors from the default exchange 2010 to use alternate ports and it seems to have solved the problem, although we are still seeing the error happening sometimes with our other dealership (who is on a different email system).  Might be some blocked ports or something on their side as well.  We have thought about moving them over to our email system  as well.  This might solve the problem.  I will update with how everything goes.

Comment: Have you tried doing telnets and stuff ? To check for open ports?

Comment: I have and I have been able to telnet to everything.

Comment: So I have reverted all of my receive connectors to the default and created 1 new one to allow authenticated relaying.  I no longer get the relaying denied when using telnet.  I do however get a new error in my message queue which is stopping alot of email from going through.  I will open a new question with it.  http://serverfault.com/questions/260190/error-451-4-4-0-dns-query-failed

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check your outgoing addresses and/or hostnames with the various anti-spam organizations. We mistakenly got on a blacklist once and this is pretty much what we saw.

Good luck getting off of it, we ended up going with a 3rd party delivery service to get past the crisis.